# Is the following subset a vector subspace of F(R,R). How to prove that it is a subspace.

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, vector-spaces

Is the following subset a vector subspace of F(R, R)?

The set of functions  f : R → R such that f(x + 2) = f(x) for all x ∈ R
I know this is obviously a subspace, but the mark scheme didn't precisely say how to prove it. I proved it like this:

let f, g ∈ V. (f+g)(x+2) = f(x+2) + g(x+2) -> f(x) + g(x) = f+g(x). 
a ∈ R. af = af(x+2) = a(f(x+2)) -> a(f(x)) = af(x). 
I'm new to proving i have no idea if this is wrong or right.

Comment: You also need to check that $0$ is in the set.

Comment: @JonHerman is everything else okay though?

Comment: Looks good. You showed closed under addition, scalar multiplication and now that it contains $0$.